# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to create an OCR application using [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29). I downloaded the Tesseract library and tested the code sample. But it is giving an error related to the `libtesseract302.dll` file. please tell me what to do exactly as I am a beginner!

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': Native library (win32-x86-64/libtesseract302.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/C:/Users/neel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tess4J/lib/jna.jar, file:/C:/Users/neel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tess4J/lib/jai_imageio.jar, file:/C:/Users/neel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tess4J/lib/ghost4j-0.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/neel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tess4J/lib/junit-4.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/neel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tess4J/build/classes/, file:/C:/Users/neel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tess4J/src/])
>       at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
>       at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
>       at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
>       at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.(TessAPI.java:38)
>       at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:286)
>       at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:222)
>       at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:173)
>       at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:158)
>       at net.sourceforge.tess4j.example.TesseractExample.main(TesseractExample.java:14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception was due to your trying to load 32-bit DLLs in a 64-bit JVM. Try again using compatible 64-bit DLLs. Check [Tess4J Usage](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/usage.html) page for updated info.

Comment: thank you! can you tell me from where can i download those files? i opened the link [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64) but the page is kind of broken or something. i can't find the link to download. can you tell me the exact path?

Comment: I just verified the Tesseract .NET wrapper link as working. Once you're in the page, click on the file(s) and select Raw to download it.

Comment: I downloaded the .dll files. Still it is giving the same error. I copied those files in main tess4j folder as well as lib folder!

Comment: i copied the dlls to system32 and got the output! thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on Tess4j and had similar issues

i  If you try to compile the code in 64-bit JVM environment then this message is likely to be shown even after you have placed the .dll files in the project folder

ii If you have not installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable (Specifically 2008) then install that first, it might work
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: how would one go about installing this on a linux app server? The link you provided looks like it's only for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Try this

-Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/ocr-tess4j-example}/dll/win32-x86-64

or

-Djna.library.path=path/to/dlls

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even I was getting the same error like "msvcr110.dll missing", then I downloaded and installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable" and it is now working fine.

Hope this will work for you as well.